# HTML POST in JAVA does not work, no errors given

Tags: java, php, html, mysql, xampp

i've been trying to debug my code for a while and trying to understand what's wrong but nothing seems to help, so i figured maybe someone here can help me.

Here is my Java code!

```
public class sql {

    static String login_url = "http://localhost/index.php";

    public static String main(String x, String y){

        try{

            String username = x;
            String password = y;

            URL url = new URL(login_url);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);

            OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));

            String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("username","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(username,"UTF-8")+"&"
                    +URLEncoder.encode("password","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(password,"UTF-8");

            bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            outputStream.close();

            // LÄSER FRÅN HEMSIDAN

            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"iso-8859-1"));
            String result="";
            String line="";
            while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){

                result += line;
            }



            //AVSLUTA CONNECTION
            bufferedReader.close();
            inputStream.close();
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();

            return result;

        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args){

        main("usr","password");


    }
}
```

and my php code:

```
<?php
$db_name = "smoothie";
$mysql_username = "root";
$mysql_password = "";
$server_name = "localhost";

$usr = $_POST["username"];
$pass = $_POST["password"];

$conn = mysql_connect($server_name,$mysql_username,$mysql_password,$db_name);

$query = "INSERT INTO members (username, password)
VALUES ('$usr','$pass')";


?>
```

im currently running the php file and the mysql through xampp!

What really bothers me is that there is no error shown neither in eclipse nor in the website. Can someone please take a look at the code and see what's missing?

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help with your issue, but I would like to recommend that you move away with the mysql implementation in PHP. It's old and [has been deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php). I would suggest using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead

Comment: Did you verify the url is correct and the php script is being executed at all?

Comment: You never connect.. If I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details. Please [edit] these details in or we may not be able to help.

Comment: okay thanks @cascer1 :)

Comment: @ArsenArsen where do i connect then?